# property binding concatenate strings angular

Tags: angular, angular2-template

How can I concatenate the below two statements. Both work by oneself.

```
<app-output [warnMessage]="myvalue | number:'1.0-1'"></app-output>

<app-output [warnMessage]="'TEXT01' | translate"></app-output>
```

Now I would like to combine both. How can I achieve this? In example something like that:

```
<app-output [warnMessage]="myvalue | number:'1.0-1' + 'TEXT01' | translate"></app-output>
```

Comment: pipes can not be combined like that. As maximum you can use few pipes on one value

Comment: Is it possible to parmeterize strings? For example "My text %1" with %1 = "some value".

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try adding some brackets

```
<app-output [warnMessage]="(myvalue | number:'1.0-1')+('TEXT01' | translate)">
</app-output>
```